# Query about sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
+--------------+---------------+
| First number | Second number |
+--------------+---------------+
|      1       |       2       |
|      2       |       3       |
|      3       |       4       |
|      4       |       5       |
+--------------+---------------+
```

So I have this table on SQL. I want to get all the descendants of a specific number. For example, if I choose number 2 the result should be:

```
+--------------+---------------+
|      2       |       3       |
|      3       |       4       |
|      4       |       5       |
+--------------+---------------+
```

Numbers don't need to be in the correct order:

```
+--------------+------------------+
| First number | Following number |
+--------------+------------------+
|      2       |       3          |
|      4       |       5          |
|      3       |       4          |
|      1       |       2          |
+--------------+------------------+
```

I should keep obtaining the previous result.

I don't know how to do it, I hope you can help me.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Your question look simple. You could easily achive your goal by coming [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Recursive CTE`

```
WITH RECURSIVE t
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   yourtable
         WHERE  "First number" = 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.*
         FROM   yourtable a
                JOIN t b
                  ON b."Second number" = a."First number")
SELECT *
FROM   t
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/UPX91506)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a simple select statement.

`select * from table where "first number" >= 2`

Comment: I didn't think about that, but the numbers may not be in the correct order, I just edited the question. Sorry about that

Comment: it doesn't matter if numbers are stored in order or not, this query will work anyway!. Anyway, as @Pham X. Bach suggested, your question is really basic, i suggest you to read a guide about SQL (just google, there's plenty online)